# Error: Cannot find module 'res' in server.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to output a "hello world" text . I'm using expressjs and using view engine called "ejs" . i'm a beginner in nodeJS

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var res = require("res");

var port = process.env.PORT;
app.set('view engine');
app.set('views',path.resolve(__dirname,'client','views'));

app.get('/',function() {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('Server running in PORT '+port);
});
```

Here is the error:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'res'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object. (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:4:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:475:10)


Process exited with code: 1
```

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res` is a function parameter for your route handler, it's not a module that you `require()`.

Try this instead:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

var port = process.env.PORT;
app.set('view engine');
app.set('views',path.resolve(__dirname,'client','views'));

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('Server running in PORT '+port);
});
```

Comment: There's no way you can be getting those particular errors with the code I provided. This is clear in the stack trace for the first error, it's still referencing line 4 of your `server.js` which is where your `require('res');` was.

The second error occurs because you only deleted line 4 and did not add the function parameters for your route handler (`app.get('/', function(req, res) {`).